# How to create a graph with all disconnected components aligned vertically?

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

using python graphviz I am trying to render a `DiGraph` where there are groups of nodes connected to each other and separate from other groups. The structure is something I am creating on the fly, where I don't really have the full picture of these components before hand, it's something I am hoping the rendered graph would help me understand. I would like for these groups to be aligned vertically in the output `svg` file instead of all laid horizontally as it is now.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add more context and maybe some implementation that you have so far?

Comment: Start with an MWE and let us know the issues you have, then we can help.

Comment: You have to be more specific, with preferably a small example. In the mean time have a look at `rankdir=LR` / `rankdir=TB`